# How can I divide one column of a data frame through another?

Tags: r, count

I wanted to divide one column by another to get the per person time how can I do this?I couldn't find anything on how you can divide.

Here is some data that I want to use

```
     min    count2.freq
263807.0    1582
196190.5    1016
586689.0    3479
```

In the end I want to add a third column like this that has the number from `min / count2.freq`

e.g `263808.0/1582 = 166.75`

Comment: just do `DF$third <- DF$min / DF$count2.freq`, assuming your matrix / data frame is called `DF`. Also, read on how operations on vectors work in R -- this is a very important basis for any work with R.

Comment: You said "*I couldn't find anything on how you can devide using R" ... `?Arithmetic` lists the basic operators. Try them all out so you can see what they do. Perhaps one of the basic introductions, such as [this one here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Statistical_Analysis:_an_Introduction_using_R/R_basics#R_as_a_calculator) might help you get going. Given `?Arithmetic`, guessing that "/" is the thing that does division (as is the case in most programs that do arithmetic on computers) would follow from [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_%28mathematics%29#Notation)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There are a plethora of ways in which this can be done. The problem is how to make R aware of the locations of the variables you wish to divide.

Assuming

```
d <- read.table(text = "263807.0    1582
196190.5    1016
586689.0    3479
")
names(d) <- c("min", "count2.freq")
> d
       min count2.freq
1 263807.0        1582
2 196190.5        1016
3 586689.0        3479
```

### My preferred way

To add the desired division as a third variable I would use `transform()`

```
> d <- transform(d, new = min / count2.freq)
> d
       min count2.freq      new
1 263807.0        1582 166.7554
2 196190.5        1016 193.1009
3 586689.0        3479 168.6373
```

### The basic R way

If doing this in a function (i.e. you are programming) then best to avoid the sugar shown above and index. In that case any of these would do what you want

```
## 1. via `[` and character indexes
d[, "new"] <- d[, "min"] / d[, "count2.freq"]

## 2. via `[` with numeric indices
d[, 3] <- d[, 1] / d[, 2]

## 3. via `$`
d$new <- d$min / d$count2.freq
```

All of these can be used at the prompt too, but which is easier to read:

```
d <- transform(d, new = min / count2.freq)
```

or

```
d$new <- d$min / d$count2.freq ## or any of the above examples
```

Hopefully you think like I do and the first version is better ;-)

The reason we don't use the syntactic sugar of `tranform()` et al when programming is because of how they do their evaluation (look for the named variables). At the top level (at the prompt, working interactively) `transform()` et al work just fine. But buried in function calls or within a call to one of the `apply()` family of functions they can and often do break.

Likewise, be careful using numeric indices (`## 2.` above); if you change the ordering of your data, you will select the wrong variables.

### The preferred way if you don't need replacement

If you are just wanting to do the division (rather than insert the result back into the data frame, then use `with()`, which allows us to isolate the simple expression you wish to evaluate

```
> with(d, min / count2.freq)
[1] 166.7554 193.1009 168.6373
```

This is again much cleaner code than the equivalent

```
> d$min / d$count2.freq
[1] 166.7554 193.1009 168.6373
```

as it explicitly states that "using `d`, execute the code `min / count2.freq`. Your preference may be different to mine, so I have shown all options.

Comment: For a beginning R user, this strikes me as a more-complicated-than-necessary solution to a pretty easy problem.

Comment: @DrewSteen Which bit? I covered most (if not all) bases here. Variables inside data frames are not visible at the top level so you either have to subset/index (as the last code chunk shows via various methods) or use the sugar of `with()`, `transform()` within()` etc. However, if you are programming the sugar can fail and subsetting/indexing is the way to go. If you are not programming, why litter your code with `[` and `$`? The other alternative is to `attach()` the data frame, but that is considered bad R code, so don't.

Comment: It's really just a matter of emphasis. I think I would lead with `d$new <- d$min / d$count2.freq` (as in "this solves your problem: read on for other alternatives") and *then* give all the other options ... thanks for omitting `attach()`.

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks. I would prefer the emphasis on on the `transform()` solution as that is how I like to do these things in reference to littering my code with `$`. But horses for courses. I will move the `with()` bit as that is extraneous, especially up front.

Comment: I would echo Drew Steen and point out that suggesting solutions such as transform to an novice user can be dangerous. Direct quote from R help for transform "If some of the values are not vectors of the appropriate length, you deserve whatever you get!". In this case a lazy evaluation of the two vectors would have been a much safer route. Whereas for me this is interesting, the poster is obviously not an R programmer and your "programming" solutions add confusion. Sometimes experts forget what it is like staring at the prompt waiting for it to do something.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans I appreciate your opinion but I disagree for several reasons. i) we are not writing documentation on [so]; if we were I probably would have approached it as per Ben's comment. As we are not I used my experience in answering. ii) your quote does not apply here; if the vectors were of different lengths the data frame would be invalid & the probability of that is now exceedingly small in R, iii) I do teach (to Geography/ecology ugrads & upwards) & in my experience the `transform()` approach is easier to understand than the equally dark magic that belies those replacement functions.

Comment: My 2 cents: with indexes and $ one should be careful if the columns get converted to factors automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Hadley Wickham

> dplyr

packages is always a saver in case of data wrangling.
To add the desired division as a third variable I would use `mutate()`

```
d <- mutate(d, new = min / count2.freq)
```

Comment: What is the difference between doing `transform(d, new = min / count2.freq)` and `mutate(d, new = min / count2.freq)`? Just that the later was written by Hadley Wickham?