# How do I calculate a ratio in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate a ratio in R but I can't seem to find the appropriate code to run it. Would any of the following work:

newvariable <- (var1/var2)

OR can I do:

mutate(DF, new variable = var1/var2)

Is this too oversimplistic? I don't have much experience with R. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `DF <- mutate(DF, new variable = var1/var2)` should work. Did you try that? What does it return?

Comment: Also, `DF$newvariable <- DF$var1 / DF$var2` should work. There are lots of ways to solve this problem, and lots of resources available to learn more about the R language e.g. https://education.rstudio.com/learn/beginner/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I divide one column of a data frame through another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13013231/how-can-i-divide-one-column-of-a-data-frame-through-another)

Comment: I tried DF <- mutate(DF, new variable = var1/var2) and the issue I now come across is that an error of "non-numeric argument to binary operator" which I assume means that my variables are not numeric. But they are in fact numeric (literally numbers and the recoded NA missing values)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R has some built-in datasets that you can use to test your code. If you type `data()` you should get a list. One dataset on the list that I use quite often is the "mtcars" dataset, e.g.

```
library(tidyverse)
data(mtcars)
df <- mtcars
head(df)
#>                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#>Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#>Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#>Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#>Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#>Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#>Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1

# Use mutate to get a new variable called "ratio"
df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(ratio = disp / hp)
head(df2)
#>                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb    ratio
#>Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 1.454545
#>Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 1.454545
#>Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 1.161290
#>Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 2.345455
#>Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 2.057143
#>Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 2.142857
```

This example uses 'tidyverse' style code. For more info, see e.g. https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/pipe-r-tutorial